# Unity: On Touch set score to zero

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to set the a score to zero whenever a certain button is pressed.

This is the script I made:

```
public class zeroOut : MonoBehaviour
{



    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    void OnMouseDown() 
    {
        scoreScript.scoreValue -= scoreScript.scoreValue;

    }



}
```

This is the scoreScript:

```
public class scoreScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static int scoreValue = 0;
    Text score;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

        score = GetComponent<Text> ();

        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        score.text = "" + scoreValue;
        
    }
}
```

Have you got any suggestions?

Comment: Attach a `Button Component` to your button through the inspector. Link a `public void` (such as your `OnMouseDown()`)  to your Button Component's onClick. In order to set a variable to 0 you can simply write `scoreScript.scoreValue = 0` without decrementing

Comment: thank you my best friend <3 <3 <3

Comment: Ehm, ok, however, I would like to know if it works 

Comment: sadly it doesn't work. Whenever I get back to the menu and load the level again the score is not zero.

Comment: Do you turn back to the menu when score is not zero and then load the level again?
This could be caused by your `static` declaration of `scoreValue`. Remove `static`

Comment: if I remove the static it gives me an error message:                                error CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'scoreScript.scoreValue'

Comment: Do you want score to be 0 when you open the level?

Comment: Yes sir. @Vinserello

Comment: Ok, you can use `static` (I don't understand the usefulness, but it should works) and, in `void Start()` of your `scoreScript` add `scoreValue = 0;`

Comment: it works. Thank you very much! <3

Comment: Is your question completly solved?